# Line breaks are being lost when sending sms from mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sms, line-breaks

For some reasons the line breaks when send SMS from MVC, not working.

I am using code like,

**Constants.cs**

```
 public struct SmsBody
    {
     public const string SMSPostResume=
"[ORG_NAME]"+
"[CONTACT_NUMBER]"+
"[ORG_NAME]"+
"[CONTACT_PERSON]"+
"[EMAIL]"+
"[MOBILE_NUMBER]";
  }
```

Then I call these variables at controller like,

```
SmsHelper.Sendsms(
            Constants.SmsSender.UserId,
            Constants.SmsSender.Password,
            Constants.SmsBody.SMSPostResume
            .Replace("[NAME],",candidate.Name)
            .Replace("[EMAIL],",candidate.Email) etc......
```

My Issue is when i get sms these all things are same line. no spacing.

**MY OUTPUT**

Dearxxxxyyy@gmail.com0000000000[QUALIFICATION][FUNCTION][DESIGNATION][PRESENT_SALARY][LOCATION][DOB][TOTAL_EXPERIENCE][GENDER] like that.

How to give space between these? Anyone know help me...

Comment: Where are the line breaks? Putting the string parts on separate lines, and concatenating them is not a line break... Have you tried putting `\n` at each place you want a line break?

Comment: ya. i tried that too. helpless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the string parts on separate lines, and concatenating them is not a line break... The parts will end up exactly after one another. You should try putting a `\n` (line break escaped sequence) at each place you want a line break:

```
public const string SMSPostResume=
    "[ORG_NAME]\n"+
    "[CONTACT_NUMBER]\n"+
    "[ORG_NAME]\n"+
    "[CONTACT_PERSON]\n"+
    "[EMAIL]\n"+
    "[MOBILE_NUMBER]\n";
```

Also a note based on @**finman**'s comment:

> Depending on the service it might be **\r\n** instead of **\n** though

So you should look up int he API docs which one would work.

Also there is another error: you try to match string constants with a `,` at their ends, and the original ones don't have that...

```
SmsHelper.Sendsms(
        Constants.SmsSender.UserId,
        Constants.SmsSender.Password,
        Constants.SmsBody.SMSPostResume
        .Replace("[NAME],",candidate.Name) // <- this line!
        .Replace("[EMAIL],",candidate.Email) // <- this line!
```

You should rewrite either the format string to include, or the replaces to exclude the `,`:

```
SmsHelper.Sendsms(
        Constants.SmsSender.UserId,
        Constants.SmsSender.Password,
        Constants.SmsBody.SMSPostResume
        .Replace("[NAME]",candidate.Name) // <- no "," this time
        .Replace("[EMAIL]",candidate.Email) // <- no "," this time
        //...etc
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Depending on the service it might be \r\n instead of \n though

Comment: @finman It is very true! Thanks for the comment, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I have a single doubt about this. In sms email field like aaagmail.com. @ symbol is not taking. why?

Answer (score 1):

```
public const string SMSPostResume=
"[ORG_NAME]"+
"\r[CONTACT_NUMBER]"+
"\r[ORG_NAME]"+
"\r[CONTACT_PERSON]"+
"\r[EMAIL]"+
"\r[MOBILE_NUMBER]";
```

Also, in

```
Replace("[NAME],",candidate.Name)
```

are you sure you want the comma after [NAME] ? If it's not in the string, don't try to replace it.